# class file for org.elasticsearch.client.Cancellable not found

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm building a spring boot application for elasticsearch 7.6.2.
I'm getting  `class file for org.elasticsearch.client.Cancellable not found` error while building.

```
public class UpdateES {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(UpdateES.class);
    public RestHighLevelClient esClient;

UpdateES(){
    int elasticPort = 9200;
    String elasticHost = "localhost";
    this.esClient = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost(elasticHost, elasticPort,"http")));
}

public void update_ES(){
    UpdateByQueryRequest request = new UpdateByQueryRequest("air_messages");
    request.setConflicts("proceed");
    request.setBatchSize(10);
    request.setScript(
            new Script(
                    ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
                    "if (ctx._source._id < 10000) {ctx._source.update += 1}",
                    Collections.emptyMap()));
    ActionListener<BulkByScrollResponse> listener = new ActionListener<BulkByScrollResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse) {
            LOGGER.info("Successfully Updated");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            LOGGER.info("Failed updating");
        }
    };
    esClient.updateByQueryAsync(request,RequestOptions.DEFAULT,listener);
}
```

}`

Answer (score 2):

Check if `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` and `elasticsearch-rest-client` are of same version in your classpath.

`compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.6.2'`

Reason - `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` transitively depends on `elasticsearch-rest-client`. Check if you explicitly mentioned lower version of rest-client. Maintain the same version for both the libraries in your classpath. If using build tool such as Maven or Gradle, they will be automatically taken care unless you explicitly override it with have a lower version.